# How can can I run tests using qtbot on macos Sonoma?

Tags: pytest, pyqt6, qt6, pytest-qt, macos-sonoma

After upgrade to MacOS Sonoma, even simple tests like

```py
def test_repro(qtbot):
    pass
```

hang indefinitely.

The related [github issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/issues/521) has been closed, without any suggested workarounds.

Can someone perhaps come up with any workarounds here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there's an ongoing discussion on the [github issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/issues/521), and the new [App Activation API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/appkit-release-notes-for-macos-14#App-Activation) is pointed out as a suspected culprit, what worked for me was to replace

```py
def _process_events():
    """Calls app.processEvents() while taking care of capturing exceptions
    or not based on the given item's configuration.
    """
    app = qt_api.QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is not None:
        app.processEvents()
```

with

```
def _process_events():
    """Calls app.processEvents() while taking care of capturing exceptions
    or not based on the given item's configuration.
    """
    app = qt_api.QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is not None:
        # app.processEvents()
        pass
```

in `pytestqt/plugin.py`.

In my case, I was able to edit it from PyCharm, it was under "External libraries -> Python 3.11 -> site-packages -> pytestqt -> plugin.py".

Not sure if it broke some other important functionality in qtbot, but at least my tests began to pass, and unblocked me in the short run.